# securesocial.core.Identity missing from SecureSocial library?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I am looking to use OAuth2 in my Play application, and I've been having trouble looking for an entry point in coding for it. SecureSocial seems like a good library to use, but there seems to be a disconnect between SecureSocial's Getting Started guide and the classes that are actually available in their library. Specifically, the guide ([here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsecuresocial.ws%2Fguide%2Finstallation.html&ei=dVY9VLOhF9CYyAS49YDICA&usg=AFQjCNGDxU8B5F6GcAZ4l3pQxgihVcWJIQ&bvm=bv.77412846,d.aWw)) says to stick [this class](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/2.1.x/samples/java/demo/app/service/InMemoryUserService.java) in as a starting UserService. However, it refers to two classes (`securesocial.core.Identity` and `securesocial.core.IdentityId`) that are supposedly in SecureSocial's jar are inexplicably missing.

Does anyone know where I can find these classes (or find some kind of up-to-date guide or really any kind of basic, barebones way to learn OAuth with Play)?

I can't post more than two links so I did not link to the jar's page in the maven repository, but search for securesocial_2.11.

Answer (score 2):

What is published -as of this writing - in Maven for Scala 2.11 is SecureSocial 3.0-M1. The published docs are for the 2.1.x version.  Identity was removed and is not needed any more. The idea is that you can specify the type you want to represent users without being forced to inherit or implement any other type.

You can read the online docs to understand some concepts and then use the samples which are updated to use the new API here: https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/3.0-M1/samples.